# Overlapping Columns Bootstrap using Container-Fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to build a webpage where I have half page image and other half text.

So far this is what I have, I have it working, just when I shrink the page, the text overlaps the photo.

.css file:

```
.z-img{
padding: 0 0 10px 0;
border: none;
border-radius: 0;
position: fixed;
}
.z-content {
padding: 70px 0 10px 0;
color: #c0d1ca
}
```

html file:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="z-img">
            <img src="...." width="732" height="432">
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="span6  text-center">
        <div class="z-content">
            <div class="well">
                <h2> About Me: </h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <blockquote>
                   <p>............</p>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

I want to ensure when I shrink the page lets say on a mobile, I do not want the text overlapping the image. Also possible to have the image shrink and enlarge according to the screen size instead of having it as a static size? I do want it to cover half the page though

Comment: You might have better luck using the `.col-*-*` classes to build your grid system.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, I just had to add the class="img-responsive" tag to my photo tag.